# SQL Server computed columns (0 if value is negative)

Tags: database, sql-server-2016, calculated-columns

I have a computed SQL Server column that is calculated like:

```
Number1 - Number2
```

If it so happens that this math is equal to a negative number I'd like to have a `0` as the value in the field rather than a negative number

IE: 5-10 = -5 (Display 0) or only positive numbers.

[image]

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN [Scheduled] - [Purchased] < 0 
          THEN 0 
          ELSE [Scheduled] - [Purchased] 
    END

SELECT 
    IIF([Scheduled] - [Purchased] < 0, 0, [Scheduled] - [Purchased])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CASE` for this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Scheduled - Purchased < 0 THEN 0 ELSE Scheduled - Purchased END
```

If using as a computed column simply write:

```
CASE WHEN Scheduled - Purchased < 0 THEN 0 ELSE Scheduled - Purchased END
```

SQL Server 2012 onwards, you can also use the `IIF` function:

```
SELECT IIF(Scheduled - Purchased < 0, 0, Scheduled - Purchased)
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use sql query with if else statements here
try with following statem,ents
or refere 
[this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/else-if-else-transact-sql)

```
IF value < 0 PRINT '0'  
ELSE PRINT 'value' ;
```

Comment: I get error messages when using `PRINT` does computed fields allow TSQL?

Comment: yes.it must work ! Do you use  Microsoft in SQL Server for running TSQL?

Comment: yes using latest version of SSMS SQL 2016, i am trying to insert this into the "Computed Column Specification, Formula" box. of my field's configuration.

Comment: i've added a screenshot hopefully that helps.